# Point on Line by distance to first point

Tags: java, math, geometry

I want to calculate a point on a line by the distance to the first point.
Because I dont have any coordinates of the new point, i can't use the linear interpolation...
I thought like this:
[**Example Drawing**](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14970834/mein%20proggen/InterpolationByDistance2.png)
(Sorry, I'm a new user and I am not allowed to post images)

But actually it doesnt work, so I ask you for help.

Here is the actual code in java:

```
    public static PointDouble interpolationByDistance(Line l, double d) {
    double x1 = l.p1.x, x2 = l.p2.x;
    double y1 = l.p1.y, y2 = l.p2.y;
    double ratioP = ratioLine_x_To_y(l);
    double disP = l.p1.distance(l.p2);
    double ratioDis = d / disP;
    PointDouble pn = l.p2.getLocation();
    pn.multi(ratioDis);
    System.out.println("dis: " + d);
    System.out.println("new point dis: " + l.p1.distance(pn));
    return pn;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You might benefit from using more descriptive variable names. I'd be willing to bet it would make your life easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a programmer you should love changing a problem to a one you have already solved. Find the ratio and then use the linear interpolation:

```
public static PointDouble interpolationByDistance(Line l, double d) {
  double len = l.p1.distance(l.p2);
  double ratio = d/len;
  double x = ratio*l.p2.x + (1.0 - ratio)*l.p1.x;
  double y = ratio*l.p2.y + (1.0 - ratio)*l.p1.y;
  System.out.println(x + ", " + y);
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, very nice algorithm! :)

Comment: Ah, I forgot to mention: line 3 should be "double ratio = d/len;". The full ratio needs to be used.

Comment: Of course you are right :) this also saves us the special case.

Answer (score 1):

The basics of this are quite simple:

```
f = 0.3;
xp = f * x1 + (1-f) * x2;
yp = f * y1 + (1-f) * y2;
```

To understand this, consider:

- if `f==0`, then `xp = x2, yp=y2`
- if `f==1`, then `xp = x1, yp=y1`
- for any value of `f` between `0..1`, you get a point between `(x1,y1)..(x2,y2)`

I'm not sure what you exactly intend to calculate. This takes a value `f` in the range `0..1`. If you have `d` as an absolute length, do `f=d/disP`